# Possible to change distributionManagement site without modifying pom.xml?

Tags: maven

We locally have a Maven ftp repository in which company-built artifacts are made available.

Suppose I branch a github project. I want to work on modifications that will take some months to complete and push back into master. I want to make changes in this branch to be built and made available internally within our company immediately. So...

- If I run mvn deploy on my github branch, it tries to deploy to sonatype or whatever is specified in the pom.xml (instead of out local ftp site).
- I'd like to not edit the distributionManagement rule of the project pom.xml since the project will eventually be merged back into the project's HEAD, and distributionManagement rules for our company are incorrect for the OSS community in general.

So, is there a way to direct mvn deploy to send the output to out local branch instead? (Perhaps by creating an additional pom.xml that somehow uses the existing one but overrides the distributionManagement rules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the answer:

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=SettingsID::default::ftp://path/to/repository deploy
```

or

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=SettingsID::default::file://path/to/repository deploy
```

... although this needs:

```
 <build>
    ...
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```